# Get matrix pixel of character?

Tags: c#, matrix, character, pixel

I want get the matrix pixel of a character with any font and size by C#. 
Any one can help me for this problem?

Comment: fonts are mostly  defined by a vectorial representation

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a font in its geometric representation if you can use WPF libraries with this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webnext/archive/2007/05/22/silverlight-convert-text-to-path.aspx
Having the "pixels" is not usually useful since text are almost all represented by vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem code by VB6 at http://www.pcworld.com.vn/hoi-dap/lap-trinh/2010/11/1222275/ma-lenh-vb6-lay-ma-tran-diem-cua-ky-tu/. But, i don't know how to convert to C#.
Everyone can help me.
best regard!